# Need help binding events to jQuery template buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery Template to create a table of information. Each row contains a minus button, plus button, and a textbox between them. There is also some text. When you click the minus or plus button, a number in the textbox either goes up or down. All of this is dynamically rendered through the template, so how will my buttons work? I've tried the following as a test, and it just ends up calling the click function on all of my minusbutton elements:

```
jQuery('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo("#holdingCell");

    jQuery('#holdingCell #minusbutton').click(
        function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });
```

Here is the relevant pieces of my code. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can make this work?

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div style="display:block;margin-bottom:20px;" id="${getNextId()}">
      <div class="adjuster"><button id='minusbutton'>-</button><input id='quantityText' class="enterQuantity" type=text style="width:40px; margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px" /><button id=">+</button></div> 
      <div class="productName" style="width:200px"><div>${productname}</div></div>
      <div class="quantity"><span style="font-weight:bold;">${quantity}</span><span> Remaining</span></div>
    </div>
```

```
function getNextId(){
return id++;
}

function buildDialog(json){
//Stuff I didn't paste here turns the parameter 'json' into a variable 'data'

 jQuery('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo("#holdingCell");

    jQuery('#holdingCell #minusbutton').click(
        function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });
```

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Do you have a working example that we can take a look at? Which id value are you expecting to be displayed? You want it to show the id of the <div> the button is contained in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your template to add onclick to each button. Then pass in the parameter that you need to send to the function:

```
<div class="adjuster"><button id='minusbutton' onClick='minusClick(${id});'>-</button>


function minusClick(id) {
    alert(id);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ //that means on page load
    $("#minusbutton").click(function(){
        var $item = $(this).parent().$("#quantityText");
        var current_value = $item.val();
        current_value = parseInt(current_value);
        if (current_value - 1 >= 0)
        {
             $item.val(current_value - 1);
        }
    })
});
```

That's the logic for the minus button. You do the equivalent for the plus with the same logic.